# Ruby wont print variable

Tags: ruby, variables, if-statement, random, puts

I've been trying to work on a fake little pin-cracking script, but somethings wrong and it's making me frustrated. It randomizes 4 numbers and checks them against 4 other numbers, but for some reason, after the numbers are guessed, it won't print them anymore.

```
#RubyCodeStart

pass1 = 4
pass2 = 9
pass3 = 2
pass4 = 8
guess = 0
flag1 = 0
flag2 = 0
flag3 = 0
flag4 = 0
loop do
    if flag1 == 0
        crack1 = rand(0..9)
    end
    if flag2 == 0
        crack2 = rand(0..9)
    end
    if flag3 == 0
        crack3 = rand(0..9)
    end
    if flag4 == 0
        crack4 = rand(0..9)
    end
    if crack1 == pass1
        crack1 = pass1
        flag1 = 1
    end
    if crack2 == pass2
        crack2 = pass2
        flag2 = 1
    end
    if crack3 == pass3
        crack3 = pass3
        flag3 = 1
    end
    if crack4 == pass4
        crack4 = pass4
        flag4 = 1
    end
    guess += 1
    puts "#{crack1} \| #{crack2} \| #{crack3} \| #{crack4} === Guess \# #{guess}"
#   if crack == pass
#       break
#   end
end
sleep(30)
```

Nothing I do works, and it refuses to print it pass it being found. I'll add data if needed.

Output:

```
8 | 0 | 6 | 1 === Guess # 1
4 | 6 | 1 | 8 === Guess # 2
 | 1 | 3 |  === Guess # 3
 | 1 | 5 |  === Guess # 4
 | 3 | 9 |  === Guess # 5
 | 3 | 3 |  === Guess # 6
 | 5 | 4 |  === Guess # 7
 | 3 | 4 |  === Guess # 8
 | 4 | 3 |  === Guess # 9
 | 0 | 6 |  === Guess # 10
 | 3 | 8 |  === Guess # 11
 | 4 | 5 |  === Guess # 12
 | 2 | 4 |  === Guess # 13
 | 8 | 7 |  === Guess # 14
 | 8 | 4 |  === Guess # 15
 | 9 | 5 |  === Guess # 16
 |  | 7 |  === Guess # 17
 |  | 5 |  === Guess # 18
 |  | 7 |  === Guess # 19
 |  | 7 |  === Guess # 20
 |  | 7 |  === Guess # 21
 |  | 1 |  === Guess # 22
 |  | 2 |  === Guess # 23
 |  |  |  === Guess # 24
 |  |  |  === Guess # 25
 |  |  |  === Guess # 26
 |  |  |  === Guess # 27
 |  |  |  === Guess # 28
 |  |  |  === Guess # 29
 |  |  |  === Guess # 30
 |  |  |  === Guess # 31
 |  |  |  === Guess # 32
 |  |  |  === Guess # 33
 |  |  |  === Guess # 34
 |  |  |  === Guess # 35
 |  |  |  === Guess # 36
 |  |  |  === Guess # 37
 |  |  |  === Guess # 38
 |  |  |  === Guess # 39
 |  |  |  === Guess # 40
```

Comment: FYI: It makes no sense to set `crack1 = pass1` inside a test for `if crack1 == pass1`. If they're already equal, making them equal again doesn't do anything.

Comment: You may want to use arrays instead of variable names with incrementing numbers. For example, `pass = [4,9,2,8]` and refer to them as `pass[0]` through `pass[3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your `crack` variables outside your loop:

```
# other variables

crack1 = 0
crack2 = 0
crack3 = 0
crack4 = 0

loop do
    # loop code
end
```

Why your code was not working?

Because in each `loop`, al `crack` variables get wiped out, because of their original scope. On every iteration, each `crack` variable is set to either `rand(0..9)` or `nil`.

So, after

```
if flag1 == 0
  crack1 = rand(0..9)
end
```

`crack1` will be set to some random number, and thus you will be able to print its value later on, but once `flag1` is not `0`, then `crack1` will be set to `nil`.

---

Taking into account the comments on your question (and adding some other tips), here's one option that will DRY your code a bit:

```
pass   = [4, 9, 2, 8]
flag   = [0, 0, 0, 0]
crack  = [0, 0, 0, 0]
guess  = 0

until crack == pass do
  (0..3).each do |i|
    crack[i] = rand(0..9) if flag[i] == 0
    flag[i] = 1 if crack[i] == pass[i]
  end

  guess += 1
  puts "#{crack.join(" | ")} === Guess \# #{guess}"
end
```

This creates the exact same output, except that it exits the loop once the password has been cracked.